# What sections should I study to prove that fifth (and up) degree polynomial equations are not solvable with Fraleigh?

Tags: abstract-algebra, soft-question

I'm Korean high school student who wants to study how to prove that degree ≥5 polynomial equations are not solvable. I know some of Set Theory and will study abstract algebra with 'A First Course in Abstract Algebra - Fraleigh'.

But I have a little time because I have to study hard other subjects to entrance into a good university. So, I want to study some part of Fraleigh.

Please let me know what sections are necessary to study that theorem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you've never studied any algebra at all before then the answer is probably "all sections".

Comment: Adding to @ErikVesterlund's answer, your goal is [Galois theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois_theory), which requires strong knowledge of both group and field theory.

Comment: Groups, Fields and Galois theory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can skip a great part of the book: at least sections 7, 11, 12, 16, 17, 21, 24, 25, 27, 28, 32, 36, 37, 38 to 47,52,54,55.
You can skip more but it would require personal contact and feed-back from you to tell you what exactly: maybe some advanced student or instructor could help.
Fraleigh is a wonderfully user-friendly book for beginners, but his fine treatment  of the homology of simplicial complexes, free groups, non-commutative rings, Gröbner bases, ... is definitely not required for your purpose.

**Full disclosure**
I am answering this question because Fraleigh was the book I taught myself abstract algebra and field theory with, a long time ago.
Understanding Kronecker's construction for creating an extension field containing a root of an irreducible polynomial over a field was one of the most exhilarating experiences in my (mathematical) life and I owe them to Fraleigh's pedagogical talent.

Comment: I'm glad it helped you, YongRyu.